# How to provide sharepoint link for plt.savefig?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sharepoint

Using python, I am trying to save the image to the sharepoint location and display the same image using img tag. I am getting the error:

File "c:/Users/Desktop/ADO_query/**pycache**/web_sc.py", line 327, in 
plt.savefig(r'https://elexon.sharepoint.com\sites...\my_plot.png')
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 954, in savefig
res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 3274, in savefig
self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2338, in print_figure
result = print_method(
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2204, in 
print_method = functools.wraps(meth)(lambda *args, **kwargs: meth(
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_api\deprecation.py", line 410, in wrapper
return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 517, in
print_png
self._print_pil(filename_or_obj, "png", pil_kwargs, metadata)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 464, in
_print_pil
mpl.image.imsave(
File "C:\Usersa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1664, in imsave
image.save(fname, **pil_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\priya.srivatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2350, in save
fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:**

```
**Code:**
```

plt.savefig(r'https://something.sharepoint.com\sites\something\Shared%20Documents\Forms\AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FSomething%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2FTeam%20Folders%2FDelivery%20phase%20teams%2F08%2E%20WP4%20%2D%20Integration%20Test%20Automation%something%2FWP4%2DMetrics%2FArchive%2FChart&viewid=dd9813b4%2D1a89%2D443f%2Dbfac%2D6f7bc09bc056&OR=Teams%2DHL&CT=1688465049675&clickparams=eyJBcHBOYW1lIjoiVGVhbXMtRGVza3RvcCIsIkFwcFZlcnNpb24iOiIyNy8yMzA2MDQwMTEzOCIsIkhhc0ZlZGVyYXRlZFVzZXIiOmZhbHNlfQ\my_plot.png')

Comment: you need a client library to access Sharepoint, for example [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload.py):